# VBA Split each cell value in specific range and add returned values to 1D array

Tags: arrays, vba, split

I have a code written that makes an array from a specific range in my worksheet

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim PackageDepthMax 
PackageDepthMax = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Package Depth(mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Package Depth(mm)").Row, LastColumn)).Value
```

Which takes all the values from my range which could look like:
[image]

What I am trying to do now is to have my "PackageDepthMax" consist of only the second integers in the value aka (100 , 110 , 120) instead of (1-100 , 1-110 ,1-120).

My attempt didn't do what I expect so I'm kinda lost

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim PackageDepthMax
PackageDepthMax = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Package Depth(mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Package Depth(mm)").Row, LastColumn)).Value, " - ")(1)
```

What's the mistake I'm making and how do I achieve the goal I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, excel will not allow split multiple columns (range of columns)  at the same time.

what about replacing unwanted symbols with "" ...
For example:

`yourRange.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""` to remove any gaps which may popout in wrong amounts

`yourRange.Replace What:="1-", Replacement:=""`  removing leading "1-" from the beginning of the value

---

or simply `yourRange.Replace "1 - ", ""`